# How do I use Japanese (and other language) file names with Amazon Cloudfront?

Tags: character-encoding, urlencode, amazon-cloudfront, content-delivery-network

http://my.domain/path/to/file/%E7%8D%85%E5%AD%90%E9%A0%AD.jpg?1371377932
This works just fine.
The browser knows to convert this to 獅子頭.

http://mycdn.cloudfront.net/path/to/file/%E7%8D%85%E5%AD%90%E9%A0%AD.jpg?1371377932
I get this error

> ERROR
>
> The request could not be satisfied.
>
> CloudFront wasn't able to connect to the origin. 
>   Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)
>   Request ID:

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you tried it yet, but you could try the Japanese characters instead of their equivalent in unicode. I tested a video name with Russian characters and it worked without problems.
AWS normally supports most character sets.
This is what I did: [http://dxxxxx.cloudfront.net/Учебная-программа.mp4](http://dxxxxx.cloudfront.net/%D0%A3%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0.mp4)
However, it may be possible that it does not work via a CNAME. I never tested that.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to do a curl request like this:

`curl -I -H "Host: my.domain" http://mycdn.cloudfront.net/path/to/file/%E7%8D%85%E5%AD%90%E9%A0%AD.jpg?1371377932`

That's usually the easiest way to test if your cdn works. There's a -I option in curl to just display the headers. Check if you're getting a 200 statuscode, and not a 404 or other strange responses.

In general dns changes might take time to be fully delegated throughout the internet. Checking can be done with tools like these: https://www.whatsmydns.net